# Exercise on algebraic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I dearly need help to proceed with the following exercise. 
Suppose I have the following map
$$
 g(x,y,z) = \begin{cases}
   [z,x] & \text{if } z \ne 0 \\
 [0,y] & \text{if } z = 0 \end{cases}
$$
from the set
$$
y^2z = x(x-z)(x-2z)
$$
to complex projective space. I would like to find its critical points and critical values, as well as the multiplicity at these values. The thing is I get an empty set of singular points, I expect otherwise so either I don't understand the task or I am doing something wrong. Denote
$$
 P(x,y,z) = y^2z - x(x-z)(x-2z) = y^2z - x^3+ 3zx^2 - 2xz^2\,.
$$
The projective curve defined by $P(x,y,z)$ is
$$
 \mathcal{C} = \{[x,y,z] \colon P(x,y,z) = 0\}
$$
Divide through by $z^3$ (for $z \neq 0$) and denote $X = \displaystyle \frac{x}{z}$, $Y = \displaystyle \frac{y}{z}$. Then we obtain
$$
 Y^2 = X(X-1)(X-2)\,,
$$
hence set
$$
 g(x,y,z) = \tilde g(X,Y) = \begin{cases}
  [1,X] = [z,x] & \text{if } z \ne 0 \\
  [0,1] = [0,y] & \text{if } z = 0 \end{cases}
$$
EDIT:
Now I can endow $\mathbb{C}$ with a complex coordinate by taking $X = x/z$ provided $z =\neq 0$, and $y$ if $z = 0$. (Is that correct?). How can I relate this to critical points ? Is it correct that the critical point is where
$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial Y} = 2Y = 0
$$
where $P(X,Y)$ is the polynomial given by the equation above? This would give me
$$
y = z
$$ 
but what does this tell me about the critical points ?? As pointed out kindly below in a comment below these should correspond to $X = 0,1$ or $2$ so $z^3 = 0$. What then are the critical values? Are the multiplicities all 1?
I struggle to make sense of this task at ll (probably this is quite obvious here)..

Any hints would be helpful! (Is there a good reference for this? I tried Kirwan but I got lost, same for the Donaldson book.)

Comment: @Martin the task started with the construction of the map given above, this is what I did so far with the help of a previous post. I was hoping to obtain some hints (even saying where I could read up on these things would be helpful) and then work out the details myself.

Comment: Yes, you are right: the set of singular points is empty. Try to show that (for $z\neq 0 $ )  $X$ is a local coordinate if $X\neq 0,1,2$ and that $Y$ is a local coordinate in the remaining cases by using  the implicit function theorem. You will see that the critical points are those with $X=0,1,2$.  Finally try to show that the point at infinity $[0,1,0]$ is a critical point too (for example because it is the *only* point of the curve sent to $[0,1]$ although  the morphism $g$ has degree $2$. Or just use the local coordinate $\frac {X}{Y}$)